# Variable reassignment in OOP languages

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

I was playing around with some variables today to get a better feel for them and I came across something that looks peculiar to me.  Here's an example in JavaScript

```
var foo = "Sethen";
var bar = foo;
var bar = "Sethen is " + bar;
console.log(bar);
```

We get the output of `Sethen is Sethen` which is not what I would expect.  What I am seeing is an assignment to `bar` and then another assignment to `bar` that overwrites the `bar` value.  I would expect to see instead `Sethen is Sethen is`.  This also happens in PHP.  Is there something fundamental I am missing here?

Why does this work as `Sethen is Sethen` when `bar` is getting assigned twice??

Comment: *"This also happens in PHP."* What exactly? I get this: http://codepad.org/jFYLlqmx.

Comment: I meant to say I am also getting `Sethen is Sethen` as well.  Question was answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bar` is assigned *after* computing the right-hand side expression.

Most assignment operators in a lot of languages have a very low precedence when it comes to order of operations.

Mozilla has a whole document on the [operator precedence of JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: I see.  Variables are evaluated before they are assigned?

Comment: Not exactly. It all has to do with expression evaluation and order of operations.

Comment: Oh okay, so the assignment operator is just low on the list for order of operations and most things happen before it.

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  Thanks for clearing that up!  I was baffled for a second.

Answer (score 1):

The expression **"Sethen is " + bar;** is executed  before the assignment

Answer (score 0):

Apart from operator precedence, you need to understand operator associativity - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Answer (score 0):

when you want to evaluate an expression in any language, the compiler(**interpreter** in **js**) first evaluate the computational portion of the expression(right side), then it stores(assigns) the evaluated value to a variable.
in this case you first have assigned `"Sethen"` to variable bar through `var bar = foo;`
in the next line you have an expression in which the compiler first evaluate `"Sethen is " + bar;`, which bar now(before assignation) holds `"Sethen"`.the evaluation leads to `"Sethen is Sethen"`.then the compiler assigns the computed value to the `bar` variable.after all steps, when you print the result, you see `"Sethen is Sethen"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
       step 1:
             var foo="sathen";
             It store string "sathen" in foo

        step 2:
              var bar=foo;
              bar value contains foos value now bar="sathen" and foo="sathen"

        step 3:     
              var bar= "sathen is " + bar
              it will replce the value of bar in right side is "sathen is" +bar value4
                 "sathen"  
         So,your ans will come "sathen is sathen"
```